# How to solve $x\ln(x) = 1$ with the Lambert W function or Newton's method

Tags: lambert-w, newton-raphson

I want to find the value of $x$ in the below equation using the Lambert W function or Newton's method.

> $$x\ln(x) = 1$$

I hope give me a details of the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you made much attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is straightforward.

**Hint:** Use the substitution $x=e^u$.

---

To solve it using [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), you have to apply:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \tag{1}$$
Using:
$$f(x)=x\ln{x}-1 \implies f'(x)=\ln{x}+1$$
Substituting into $(1)$, you obtain:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n\ln(x_n)-1}{\ln(x_n)+1} \tag{2}$$
It just remains to choose a suitable value for $x_0$ and apply $(2)$ recursively.